# Python MySQLdb query parameters "IS NULL" instead of "= NULL"

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm working on a Python script to import data to a MySQL database. 
I use MySQLdb to execute my queries.

I also use a function to set a query and its data with named parameters to be automatically replaced inside the request, such as:

```
req = "SELECT * FROM sample WHERE `id` = %(id)s and `param1` = %(param1)s"
data = {'id': 15, 'param1': None}
cursor.execute(req, data)
```

I really like this way because I'm using the same data `dict` for 3 or 4 queries.

The problem is when I try to make a `WHERE` condition with `None` value, it does replace my `None` by `NULL` but I would like it to be able to replace a `` `param1` = NULL `` by `` `param1` IS NULL ``, so that the condition  evaluates to true.

Is there any way to solve this issue directly? Or can I use just the parameter replace (without executing the query), then do a replace on my own (`= NULL` to `IS NULL`), and then execute the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like the following.

```
def query(params):
    # Make sure it's hardcoded and malicious user can't overwrite it
    param_whitelist = 'id', 'param1'

    sql = '''
        SELECT * 
        FROM sample 
        WHERE {placeholders}
    '''
    placeholders = ' AND '.join(
        '`{field}` {op} %s'.format(field=k, op='IS' if params[k] is None else '=') 
        for k in param_whitelist)
    sql = sql.format(placeholders=placeholders)

    cursor.execute(sql, params)
    return cursor


data = {'id': 15, 'param1': None}
print([r for r in query(data)])
```

Comment: @m.nachury Initially I've pasted not the latest version of the snippet where `param_whitelist` is not used. It's fixed in the update.